# Physical Interpretation of the parameters of the thin-membrane problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

I am working in the numerical solution of the thin membrane problem. I'd like to know the interpretation of the terms in the equation in order to interpret the results correctly.I don't have them because I am studying it from a mathematical point of view, so I don't know how it was derived but physical interpretation is useful.

The equation is supposed to model the behavior of a thin membrane when a given force is applied to it if the membrane material is not homogeneous, that's model by $a(x,y)= x^2 + 1$. The domain is the unit square $\Omega= [0,1]\times [0,1]$. The equation is

$$ -\nabla\cdot(a(x,y)\nabla u) = f(x,y)\text{ ; on } \Omega$$

$$u = 0 \text{  ; in } \Omega$$

I am supposed to choose different source terms $f(x,y)$

**a) I am only told that the membrane material is not homogeneous, so what does $a(x,y)$ represent? the surface density of the membrane? or something else?**

**b) Is the force $-f(x)$ representing the component of a force along the $z$ axis?**

**c) Does the model took into account gravity? That's important for my physical interpretation to be correct**

My physical interpretation is:

In order to have an exact solution to compare my numerical solution with I chose a function that vanishes on the boundary, the simplest one I guess is $u(x,y) = xy(x-1)(y-1)$ and found the value of $f(x,y)$ that produces it which is

$f(x,y) = -(6x^2y^2 - 6x^2y - 2xy^2 + 2xy + 2y^2 -2y + 2x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x^2 - 2x)$
so that $F(x,y) = -f(x,y)$ substituted in the equations cancel that $-$ sign that mathematicians like to put in Poisson's equation:
$$ \nabla\cdot(a(x,y)\nabla u) = F(x,y)\text{ ; on } \Omega$$

I guess this must be closer to a physical derivation and if I can interpret $F$ as the component of the  force along the $z$ axis, the plots of $F(x,y), a(x,y)$ and $u(x,y)$ would make sense physically:
Since I can see that in the zone of the domain where $a(x,y)$ is greater,supposing that's density,
the force $F(x,y)$ which is positive in the whole domain is greater, so it's an upwards force that is greater where the density is. That's why the plot of $u(x,y)$ is bulging up simmetrically, because the force is compensating the greater density by applying more force where is it denser and less force where is it less dense.

If someone knows the derivation or where to find it, it would be a plus too!
Thank you

a(x,y):

[image]

f(x,y):

[image]

u(x,y):

[image]

Comment: The equation looks like that of an elastic or extensible membrane subjected to a transverse load (so yes, $f(x,y)$ is in the $z$ direction and could represent gravity if the membrane is oriented horizontally). The deflection occurs from stretching, so $a(x,y)$ represents an effective stiffness that varies over the membrane and generally tends to pull it back to flatness again. Does this get at what you're asking about? This should provide enough keywords to locate a derivation of the equation, possibly relying on energy minimization or a force balance.

Comment: @Chemomechanics , so a(x,y) is not density, but stiffness?. If u is displacemente and F is force I guess I can do a dimensional analisis to discover the units of a. Would the nablas be lenght^-1?.  If it is stiffness I guess my interpretation is more accurate now than with density

Comment: $f$ is the areal loading (Pa).  $a$ can be the biaxial stretching modulus (Pa).  $u$ and the gradient are often normalized by the side length (so unitless).